# GLASSFISH4 deltaspike1.0 JTA EJB3 ERROR

Tags: transactions, glassfish, ejb, jta, deltaspike

hello everyone I developed a very serious problem encountered!!!

Environmental below:

GlassFish 4  ,deltaspike1.0,JPA2.1/HIBERNATE,EJB3.1**

***my EntityManager :***

```
@ApplicationScoped

public class EntityManagerProducer implements java.io.Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = -4668876918252759251L;

private @PersistenceContext(unitName = "fruitStoreDB")

EntityManager em;


private @PersistenceContext(unitName = "picketlink") 
EntityManager picketlink;

@FruitStoreDB
@Produces

public EntityManager createManager() {
 return em;
}



@Produces
@PicketLink
public EntityManager createPicketLinkEntityManager() {
return picketlink;
}

}



 ***my deltaspike ManagerResolver***

public class FruitStoreManagerResolver implements EntityManagerResolver{


private @Inject @FruitStoreDB EntityManager fruitStore;

@Override
public EntityManager resolveEntityManager() {
return fruitStore;
}
```

***My SysMenuRepository :***

```
@Repository

@EntityManagerConfig(entityManagerResolver = FruitStoreManagerResolver.class, flushMode = FlushModeType.COMMIT)

public interface SysMenuRepository extends EntityRepository<SysMenu, Long>, 
java.io.Serializable {}



  **My EJB:**

@Stateless

public class SysMenuFacade extends AbstractFacade<SysMenu> {

private @Inject @FruitStoreDB EntityManager fruitStore;

 private @Inject SysMenuRepository sysMenuRepository;

public SysMenu findMenuByKey(long key){
 if(key ==0){

  return new SysMenu();

}

return fruitStore.find(SysMenu.class, key);

}

}
```

**My CDI**

```
    @Named
    @ViewScoped
    public class SysMenuQuery implements java.io.Serializable {
    private @Inject
    SysMenuRepository sysMenuRepository;

    private @Inject
    SysMenuFacade sysMenuFacade;

   public void initSource() {

   root = new DefaultTreeNode(menu", null);

   createTreeNode(sysMenuRepository.findRootList(), root);//Normal operation

   System.out.println(sysMenuFacade.findAll());


**//ERROR ： javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Lookup of java:comp/UserTransaction not allowed for Container managed Transaction beans**
    }
}
```

**Now EJB JTA transaction and deltaspike1 the DATA module can not be used with a transaction, and now only SysMenuRepository Data module is easy to use. EJB transaction does not work well. XA transaction GLassfish4 use**

My Exception :

```
javax.ejb.EJBException: javax.ejb.EJBException: javax.ejb.CreateException: Could not create stateless EJB
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.StatelessSessionContainer._getContext(StatelessSessionContainer.java:435)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.getContext(BaseContainer.java:2516)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.preInvoke(BaseContainer.java:1906)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.java:210)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.java:88)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy513.findAll(Unknown Source)
    at com.songsoft.service.__EJB31_Generated__SysMenuFacade__Intf____Bean__.findAll(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.Reflections.invokeAndUnwrap(Reflections.java:396)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.EnterpriseBeanProxyMethodHandler.invoke(EnterpriseBeanProxyMethodHandler.java:108)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.EnterpriseTargetBeanInstance.invoke(EnterpriseTargetBeanInstance.java:56)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.InjectionPointPropagatingEnterpriseTargetBeanInstance.invoke(InjectionPointPropagatingEnterpriseTargetBeanInstance.java:63)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ProxyMethodHandler.invoke(ProxyMethodHandler.java:101)
    at com.songsoft.service.SysMenuFacade$Proxy$_$$_Weld$EnterpriseProxy$.findAll(Unknown Source)
    at com.songsoft.action.SysMenuQuery.initSource(SysMenuQuery.java:59)
    at com.songsoft.action.SysMenuQuery$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.initSource(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at javax.el.ELUtil.invokeMethod(ELUtil.java:326)
    at javax.el.BeanELResolver.invoke(BeanELResolver.java:536)
    at javax.el.CompositeELResolver.invoke(CompositeELResolver.java:256)
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:269)
    at com.sun.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:304)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.el.ForwardingMethodExpression.invoke(ForwardingMethodExpression.java:40)
    at org.jboss.weld.el.WeldMethodExpression.invoke(WeldMethodExpression.java:50)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:105)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.core.DeclarativeSystemEventListener.processEvent(EventHandler.java:128)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent$ComponentSystemEventListenerAdapter.processEvent(UIComponent.java:2563)
    at javax.faces.event.SystemEvent.processListener(SystemEvent.java:108)
    at javax.faces.event.ComponentSystemEvent.processListener(ComponentSystemEvent.java:118)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationImpl.processListeners(ApplicationImpl.java:2187)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationImpl.invokeComponentListenersFor(ApplicationImpl.java:2135)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationImpl.publishEvent(ApplicationImpl.java:289)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationImpl.publishEvent(ApplicationImpl.java:247)
    at javax.faces.application.ApplicationWrapper.publishEvent(ApplicationWrapper.java:726)
    at javax.faces.application.ApplicationWrapper.publishEvent(ApplicationWrapper.java:726)
    at javax.faces.application.ApplicationWrapper.publishEvent(ApplicationWrapper.java:726)
    at javax.faces.application.ApplicationWrapper.publishEvent(ApplicationWrapper.java:726)
    at org.apache.deltaspike.jsf.impl.injection.InjectionAwareApplicationWrapper.publishEvent(InjectionAwareApplicationWrapper.java:121)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:107)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:219)
    at org.apache.deltaspike.jsf.impl.listener.request.DeltaSpikeLifecycleWrapper.render(DeltaSpikeLifecycleWrapper.java:111)
    at javax.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleWrapper.render(LifecycleWrapper.java:92)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:647)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:344)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
    at org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter.doFilter(FileUploadFilter.java:98)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
    at com.songsoft.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:41)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
    at org.apache.deltaspike.servlet.impl.event.EventBridgeFilter.doFilter(EventBridgeFilter.java:59)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
    at org.apache.deltaspike.servlet.impl.produce.RequestResponseHolderFilter.doFilter(RequestResponseHolderFilter.java:63)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:316)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:357)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:260)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:188)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:191)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:168)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:189)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:288)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:136)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:114)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:838)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:113)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:115)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:55)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:135)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:564)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:544)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: javax.ejb.EJBException: javax.ejb.CreateException: Could not create stateless EJB
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.StatelessSessionContainer$SessionContextFactory.create(StatelessSessionContainer.java:700)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.util.pool.NonBlockingPool.getObject(NonBlockingPool.java:246)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.StatelessSessionContainer._getContext(StatelessSessionContainer.java:430)
    ... 90 more
Caused by: javax.ejb.CreateException: Could not create stateless EJB
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.StatelessSessionContainer.createStatelessEJB(StatelessSessionContainer.java:514)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.StatelessSessionContainer.access$000(StatelessSessionContainer.java:97)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.StatelessSessionContainer$SessionContextFactory.create(StatelessSessionContainer.java:698)
    ... 92 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Exception attempting to inject Env-Prop: org.apache.deltaspike.jpa.impl.transaction.BeanManagedUserTransactionStrategy/userTransaction@Field-Injectable Resource. Class name = org.apache.deltaspike.jpa.impl.transaction.BeanManagedUserTransactionStrategy Field name=userTransaction@java.lang.String@java:comp/UserTransaction@@ into class org.apache.deltaspike.jpa.impl.transaction.BeanManagedUserTransactionStrategy: Lookup failed for 'java:comp/env/org.apache.deltaspike.jpa.impl.transaction.BeanManagedUserTransactionStrategy/userTransaction' in SerialContext[myEnv={java.naming.factory.initial=com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialInitContextFactory, java.naming.factory.state=com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl, java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=com.sun.enterprise.naming}
    at org.glassfish.weld.services.InjectionServicesImpl.aroundInject(InjectionServicesImpl.java:145)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.InjectionContextImpl.run(InjectionContextImpl.java:46)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.DefaultInjector.inject(DefaultInjector.java:64)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.BasicInjectionTarget.inject(BasicInjectionTarget.java:91)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.ManagedBean.create(ManagedBean.java:158)
    at org.jboss.weld.context.unbound.DependentContextImpl.get(DependentContextImpl.java:69)
    at org.jboss.weld.manager.BeanManagerImpl.getReference(BeanManagerImpl.java:716)
    at org.jboss.weld.manager.BeanManagerImpl.getReference(BeanManagerImpl.java:774)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.FieldInjectionPoint.inject(FieldInjectionPoint.java:92)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.Beans.injectBoundFields(Beans.java:368)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.Beans.injectFieldsAndInitializers(Beans.java:377)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.DefaultInjector.inject(DefaultInjector.java:72)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.ResourceInjector.inject(ResourceInjector.java:60)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.DefaultInjector$1.proceed(DefaultInjector.java:66)
    at org.glassfish.weld.services.InjectionServicesImpl.aroundInject(InjectionServicesImpl.java:142)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.InjectionContextImpl.run(InjectionContextImpl.java:46)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.DefaultInjector.inject(DefaultInjector.java:64)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.BasicInjectionTarget.inject(BasicInjectionTarget.java:91)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.ManagedBean.create(ManagedBean.java:158)
    at org.jboss.weld.context.unbound.DependentContextImpl.get(DependentContextImpl.java:69)
    at org.jboss.weld.manager.BeanManagerImpl.getReference(BeanManagerImpl.java:716)
    at org.jboss.weld.manager.BeanManagerImpl.getReference(BeanManagerImpl.java:774)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.FieldInjectionPoint.inject(FieldInjectionPoint.java:92)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.Beans.injectBoundFields(Beans.java:368)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.Beans.injectFieldsAndInitializers(Beans.java:377)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.DefaultInjector.inject(DefaultInjector.java:72)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.ResourceInjector.inject(ResourceInjector.java:60)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.DefaultInjector$1.proceed(DefaultInjector.java:66)
    at org.glassfish.weld.services.InjectionServicesImpl.aroundInject(InjectionServicesImpl.java:142)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.InjectionContextImpl.run(InjectionContextImpl.java:46)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.DefaultInjector.inject(DefaultInjector.java:64)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.BasicInjectionTarget.inject(BasicInjectionTarget.java:91)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.ManagedBean.create(ManagedBean.java:158)
    at org.jboss.weld.context.unbound.DependentContextImpl.get(DependentContextImpl.java:69)
    at org.jboss.weld.manager.BeanManagerImpl.getReference(BeanManagerImpl.java:716)
    at org.jboss.weld.manager.BeanManagerImpl.getReference(BeanManagerImpl.java:738)
    at org.apache.deltaspike.partialbean.impl.PartialBeanLifecycle.createHandlerInstance(PartialBeanLifecycle.java:178)
    at org.apache.deltaspike.partialbean.impl.PartialBeanLifecycle.create(PartialBeanLifecycle.java:116)
    at org.apache.deltaspike.core.util.bean.ImmutableBean.create(ImmutableBean.java:72)
    at org.jboss.weld.context.unbound.DependentContextImpl.get(DependentContextImpl.java:69)
    at org.jboss.weld.manager.BeanManagerImpl.getReference(BeanManagerImpl.java:716)
    at org.jboss.weld.manager.BeanManagerImpl.getReference(BeanManagerImpl.java:774)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.FieldInjectionPoint.inject(FieldInjectionPoint.java:92)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.Beans.injectBoundFields(Beans.java:368)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.Beans.injectFieldsAndInitializers(Beans.java:377)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.DefaultInjector.inject(DefaultInjector.java:72)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.StatelessSessionBeanInjector.inject(StatelessSessionBeanInjector.java:50)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.DefaultInjector$1.proceed(DefaultInjector.java:66)
    at org.glassfish.weld.services.InjectionServicesImpl.aroundInject(InjectionServicesImpl.java:142)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.InjectionContextImpl.run(InjectionContextImpl.java:46)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.DefaultInjector.inject(DefaultInjector.java:64)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.BasicInjectionTarget.inject(BasicInjectionTarget.java:91)
    at org.glassfish.weld.services.JCDIServiceImpl.injectEJBInstance(JCDIServiceImpl.java:257)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.injectEjbInstance(BaseContainer.java:1683)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.StatelessSessionContainer.createStatelessEJB(StatelessSessionContainer.java:475)
    ... 94 more
Caused by: com.sun.enterprise.container.common.spi.util.InjectionException: Exception attempting to inject Env-Prop: org.apache.deltaspike.jpa.impl.transaction.BeanManagedUserTransactionStrategy/userTransaction@Field-Injectable Resource. Class name = org.apache.deltaspike.jpa.impl.transaction.BeanManagedUserTransactionStrategy Field name=userTransaction@java.lang.String@java:comp/UserTransaction@@ into class org.apache.deltaspike.jpa.impl.transaction.BeanManagedUserTransactionStrategy: Lookup failed for 'java:comp/env/org.apache.deltaspike.jpa.impl.transaction.BeanManagedUserTransactionStrategy/userTransaction' in SerialContext[myEnv={java.naming.factory.initial=com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialInitContextFactory, java.naming.factory.state=com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl, java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=com.sun.enterprise.naming}
    at com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.util.InjectionManagerImpl._inject(InjectionManagerImpl.java:717)
    at com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.util.InjectionManagerImpl.inject(InjectionManagerImpl.java:484)
    at com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.util.InjectionManagerImpl.injectInstance(InjectionManagerImpl.java:170)
    at org.glassfish.weld.services.InjectionServicesImpl.aroundInject(InjectionServicesImpl.java:138)
    ... 148 more
Caused by: javax.naming.NamingException: Lookup failed for 'java:comp/env/org.apache.deltaspike.jpa.impl.transaction.BeanManagedUserTransactionStrategy/userTransaction' in SerialContext[myEnv={java.naming.factory.initial=com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialInitContextFactory, java.naming.factory.state=com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl, java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=com.sun.enterprise.naming} [Root exception is javax.naming.NamingException: Lookup failed for 'java:comp/UserTransaction' in SerialContext[myEnv={java.naming.factory.initial=com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialInitContextFactory, java.naming.factory.state=com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl, java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=com.sun.enterprise.naming, com.sun.enterprise.naming.logicalName=java:comp/env/org.apache.deltaspike.jpa.impl.transaction.BeanManagedUserTransactionStrategy/userTransaction} [Root exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Lookup of java:comp/UserTransaction not allowed for Container managed Transaction beans]]
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:491)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:438)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:411)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:411)
    at com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.util.InjectionManagerImpl._inject(InjectionManagerImpl.java:613)
    ... 151 more
Caused by: javax.naming.NamingException: Lookup failed for 'java:comp/UserTransaction' in SerialContext[myEnv={java.naming.factory.initial=com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialInitContextFactory, java.naming.factory.state=com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl, java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=com.sun.enterprise.naming, com.sun.enterprise.naming.logicalName=java:comp/env/org.apache.deltaspike.jpa.impl.transaction.BeanManagedUserTransactionStrategy/userTransaction} [Root exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Lookup of java:comp/UserTransaction not allowed for Container managed Transaction beans]
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:491)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:438)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:411)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:411)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.util.JndiNamingObjectFactory.create(JndiNamingObjectFactory.java:90)
    at com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.ComponentEnvManagerImpl$1.create(ComponentEnvManagerImpl.java:714)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.GlassfishNamingManagerImpl.lookup(GlassfishNamingManagerImpl.java:745)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.GlassfishNamingManagerImpl.lookup(GlassfishNamingManagerImpl.java:715)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.JavaURLContext.lookup(JavaURLContext.java:159)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:471)
    ... 155 more
Caused by: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Lookup of java:comp/UserTransaction not allowed for Container managed Transaction beans
```

**Please help me. Really do not know how to solve the**